# Accessing Objective-C header properties from Swift subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I came late to the party and just switched to Swift. I will, however, continue using my libraries written in Objective-C but I'm having trouble accessing parent classes' properties from Swift. A typical structure looks like:

`A.swift -> B.h -> C.h`

Where A is part of a project that uses an Objective-C library. I've added the B and C header files in my bridging header and everything works fine. The only issue I'm having is accessing the public properties of my header files. For instance,

```
// C.h
@interface C
@property(nonatomic, readonly) Foo *foo
@end
```

Would normally be accessed with dot syntax from any subclass written in Objective-C. In Swift, instances of A do not appear to have members of type Foo. The only solution I have found so far is to manually add getters to all my properties but I would rather not modify my libraries' source code. Is there another approach or am I missing something?

Comment: Hae you tried to access using .valueForKey("foo")  for class instances?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but could not...  I had no trouble accessing an Objective-C property from a Swift sub-class.  A few thoughts...  Does `C` inherit from `NSObject`?  You would have other problems if it didn't, though.  Is `Foo` visible to Swift via the bridging header?

Comment: @OmniProg I found the problem. The real structure looked more like: A.swift -> B.h -> C.h -> D.h. And I wasn't including C in my bridging header. So the solution is to include all headers of A's superclasses. Thank you!